# Raspberry Pi 2 Some GPIO pins not working

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I've created a small app to test all GPIO pins if working correctly. 
But on some pins, 21 for example, application threw an error: `Element not found. Failed to open a handle to the device.` Is this normal?

Pins that worked: 4-6; 12-13; 16; 18; 22-27;

Why is that happening?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015RC C++. with Windows 10 Pro build 10130

**Edit:** *Numbers above are BCM numbers*

Comment: @Funkyguy Code is alright. Only a few pins didn't work.

Comment: @Funkyguy Actually calling OpenPin function failed with the error above. Here's how I call OpenPin func: `mPin = GpioController::GetDefault()->OpenPin(pinPos);`

Comment: You should check the assignment of each "GPIO" to ensure that the pin is GPIO rather than assigned to a peripheral (aka alternate) function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622586/how-gpio-is-mapped-in-memory/31625406#31625406 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635576/whats-the-relationship-between-gpio-and-spi

Comment: are you sure there isn't an application running in the background that's already opened that pin?

Comment: @vidalsasoon Yeah I'm sure. Reinstalling IoT extension solved the problem, but I don't know what it caused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the alternate functions of those pins. They cannot be used as general purpose IO. For a full list see [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs) (note: the BCM2836 of the Raspberry Pi 2 shares the same peripheral layout as the BCM2835 as listed here).

> 0..3  I2C serial interface (I2C0, I2C1)
>
> 7..11  SPI serial interface (SPI0)
>
> 14..15 UART asynchronous serial interface
>
> 17, 19..21  SPI serial interface (SPI1)

Answer (score 2):

Im also new to Raspberry but searching I found that Microsoft reserved GPIO 19,20,21,17 as SPI1 signal, so we can't use these pin as normal GPIO

SOURCE:
http://www.pridopia.co.uk/pi-edu-v02-win10.html